# How to show contents in same way on different Mobile Platform?

Tags: android, html, ios, mobile, cross-platform

I hope to show a dynamic generated HTML page on my mobile application. This HTML file is in fixed structured. Include forms, Images, and buttons. However, when it comes to different mobile platform, like ios and android. And also different cell phone, like android from sumsung or other company. The display result are different. Some of them are very bad. This problem is heavier for android system since there are many different company using this system.

For now I'm using a method that when user using the application, the application will send request with the cell phone model user use. And the server side will choose the correct HTML template for that phone. That means I have to write a HTML template for every phone. Consider the increase phone models these days, I don't think it is a wise idea.

I hope if someone could help me came up a solution to sovle this problem. Either a solution that will dynamic generate HTML templates based on user's cell phone model, or a universal way to create a HTML will fits all mobile display.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just show the HTML page in a webView and let the the OS handle the look and feel of the mobile page? Creating a diff. html template for each type of device seems extremely implausible

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly your problem I would highly recommend using Twitter Bootstrap to design your html pages. This is very easy to use and with this you can design webpages which resize themselves as per the screen. The responsive css defined in twitter bootstrap handles all screen sizes for you and renders html pages on the fly as per screen size without hampering/distorting the look and feel of your html code.

You can get the source and learn everything about it from here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

This is a demo page made using twitter boot strap. You can try and open it in a browser window and then resize the window to see how the page contents re-arrange themselves

http://brocknunn.com/bootstrap-untame/

Also following are some tuts which help you get up to speed with Twitter Bootstrap

http://untame.net/2012/07/twitter-bootstrap-part-1-what-is-bootstrap-anyway/

http://untame.net/2012/07/twitter-bootstrap-part-2-design-a-responsive-homepage/

I just used this for one of my Android apps where I had custom html pages. It saved me a lot of effort and time. I only had to invest a few hours to learn how things need to be arranged in the html page and I was all set. I hope this will help you in greatly reducing your manual effort and save a lot of time.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust your design to scale things in relative sizes.  Android has a technique for sizing applications for different devices, you should do the same and create a generic site template for a range of devices.

For example, work with percentages, and provide a different template for devices that have screen sizes over 5 inches.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend giving phone gap a look (http://phonegap.com/)

Also, you should definitely be using percentages in your css to be compatible across all resolutions (including desktop and laptop)

Gone are the days of being able to say this is what my site looks like you better make your resolution match it!!

Also consider offering just 2 types of site a mobile (with all images made smaller) and a desktop which has the fuller sized images.